# Add table values to input field on button click

Tags: javascript, input, datatable

I have a DataTable that stores names only. I want to have a button that will add all the names in the DataTable to an text input field.

```
    <div id="myTabDiv">
<table name="mytab" id="mytab1">
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>chris</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>mike</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <button id="add" >ADD</button>
    <input type="text" id="text">
</div>
```

After click the "add" button, I want the names to appear in the text field separated by a comma.

And if possible, If the button is clicked again, remove the names?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is less of a question to explain a confusion and more of a work order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the whole solution on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNvyZK). This is the function used:

```
var clicks = 0;
function csv() {
  var box = document.getElementsByName('text')[0];

  if(clicks === 0){
    var newcsv = "";
    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");  
    for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++)
    {
      newcsv += tds[i].innerHTML;
      if(i != tds.length-1) newcsv += ",";
    }
    box.value = newcsv;
    clicks++;
  }
  else{
    clicks = 0;
    box.value = "";
  }
}
```

This is bound to onclick event of a button.

Comment: This is because you changed my code. You set table's name to "TD". Did you check the codepen. It works there.

Answer (score 0):

Assign id to input

```
<input type=text id="textbox"/>
```

Just loop though table

```
 var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
    var textbox=document.getElementById("textbox")
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
       for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
         if(textbox.value=="")
            {
               textbox.value=row.cells[j].innerText;
            }
         else
            {
               textbox.value+= textbox.value+','+row.cells[j].innerText;
             }
       }  
    }
```

Comment: Thn\anks for the answer. I tried something similar to this but it keeps just adding "undefined" to the text

Comment: It is working in jsfiddle that you have posted....Whtz the problem???Jst recheck  the logic....